# Как правильно: не в чем/чём было себя упрекнуть?

Tags: словосочетания, е-или-ё

Мне на слух более звучным кажется вариант:

> **не в чем** было себя упрекнуть (ударение на **не**)

При этом в литературе в редких случаях встречается вариант:

> Скорее всего, ей **не в чём** было себя упрекнуть.
>
> Ему **не в чём** было оправдываться.

Который мне кажется менее естественным. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: _ДеNiZz: При этом в литературе, в редких случаях встречается..._ === Хоть один пример написания _**не в чём**_  (с _**ё**_) сможете привести?

Comment: @slava1947 Я нашёл два приведённых примера в Интернете, в авторских рассказах. Что, конечно, не делает их корректными. Поэтому и уточняю.

Answer (score 3):

Видимо, вы встречали *похожее* выражение:

> она н**и** в чЁм не могла себя упрекнуть.

В нём тоже единственный вариант ударения.

Answer (score 2):

> *...**не в чем** было себя упрекнуть* (ударение на ***не***)
>
> *Скорее всего, ей **не в чём** было себя упрекнуть.*
>
> *Ему **не в чём** было оправдываться.*

.

Из приведённых в вопросе вариантов корректен только первый:

*...**не в чем** было себя упрекнуть.*

См. [**словарь**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC&all=x):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же и в *"Орфографическом словаре русского языка" Б.З. Букчиной,  И.К.Сазоновой и Л.К. Чельцовой (М., 2016):*

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Его есть в чём упрекнуть. - Его не в чём упрекнуть.

Пишется Ё, а вот произносится действительно ЧЕМ. Так как в русском языке Ё всегда ударная, а ударение в выражении НЕ В ЧЁМ всегда падает на НЕ, то на месте Ё произносится [Ь].

Примеров много в нацкорпусе, вот один из них:

"Мне не в чём выйти, не в чём ходить, стыдно на людях показаться… [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977)] [Нацкорпус. Поиск][1](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E5%20%E2%20%F7%B8%EC)

Comment: _Екатерина Каштанова: Пишется Ё, а вот произносится действительно ЧЕМ._ === **Екатерина**, Вы меня улыбнули...

Comment: Приятно, когда люди улыбаются. В ответе я уверена.. Не забывайте, что с местоимением ЧТО употреблён предлог В, требующий предложного падежа. Форма местоимения ЧТО в предложном падеже - В ЧЁМ, О ЧЁМ.